# Facebook PHP SDK Error validating access token via HTTPS URL

Tags: php, facebook, authentication

i have an issue with an request on Facebook SDK (graph v2.2). I'm using multiple APPs calling the same way successfully, but one URL doesnt work in any way, always returning the following Error:

> Graph returned an error: Kann URL nicht laden: Die Domain dieser URL ist nicht in den Domains der App vorhanden. Um diese URL laden zu können, füge alle Domains und Subdomains deiner App im Appdomain-Feld in deinen App-Einstellungen hinzu.

My Facebook Initialisation

```
$this->facebook = new Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id' => $appdata['ApplicationKey'],
    'app_secret' => $appdata['SecretApplicationKey'],
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2',
]);
```

And the Callback Method

```
$helper = $this->facebook->getRedirectLoginHelper();

try {
    $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
    $this->setErrorMessage('Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage());
    return false;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    $this->setErrorMessage('Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage());
    return false;
}
```

Im calling 4 different apps this way, all working except the one which uses HTTPS. I couldnt find any information if there is any difference when using a callback URL over https.

Maybe the problem isnt https, but im pretty clueless what else could be... i know the error message says that my app domain doesnt fit, but i checked my app settings now like 15 times and they are (pretty sure) correct.

OAuth Redirect URL is set, app Domains is set and URL of website is also.

Other app logins with nearly same settings except the different URL are working without any problems.

Anyone have an idea?

Thanks in advice
Chris

Comment: Check that the _exact same_ value (minus URL encoding, of course) of the redirect_uri parameter in the login dialog call is set as a Valid OAuth Redirect URI.

Comment: my App Domains are `www.domain.de` and `domain.de`
(Facebook automatic removes https or http here)

URL of Website is `https://www.domain.de/socialmedia/login`

OAuth Redirect is `https://www.domain.de/socialmedia/login-callback`
and the URL i'm calling for Login `https://www.facebook.com/v2.2/dialog/oauth?client_id=xxxxx&state=xxxxxxx&response_type=code&sdk=php-sdk-5.2.0&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.domain.de%2Fsocialmedia%2Flogin-callback&scope=email%2Cpublic_profile%2Cpublish_pages%2Cmanage_pages`

i really dont see any mistakes there

Comment: Try setting website to `https://www.domain.de/socialmedia/`, so that your redirect URI is actually below that path.

Comment: tried this, didnt help

Answer (score 0):

found a solution... if i change the https to http in my redirect_uri parameter from the facebook link it works, even if my page still uses https.

But i'm still not really sure what the problem with https is.